# Get non duplicate values from one of the provided list

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

The problem which can be solved in java 7 way but not sure how to implement in java 8. I have two list of integer

```
List<Interger> one = [1,2,4]
List<Interger> two= [2,3]

Excepted output = [3]
```

It means found non unique values from one of the list. I want to achieve this in java 8 using collection streams. Thanks in advance

Comment: what can be solved "in Java 7 way" can be used as is in Java 8... it would help to see the actual Java 7 code to make you further suggestions...

Comment: is your Java 7 code just: `two.removeAll(one)`? then: just keep that...

Comment: @Roland Totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need streams here.

Simply remove all `one`'s elements from `two`:

```
two.removeAll(one);
```

Or if you want to leave `two` unchanged:

```
List<Integer> diff = new ArrayList<>(two);
diff.removeAll(one);
```